# Django how to anotate number of attempts in Queryset

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the model like:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    title_2 = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    attempts = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

And what I want to achive in my anotation I need a number of attempt based on older updated_at value. But active order have `attempts=None`.
How I can correctly anotate the number of attempt ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by having a `self` related `fk` you are going to have some serious data duplication in your database. Since you would have to recreate the `Order` and its values and set the `attempt` related to the first one. To avoid duplicated fields, create another table to hold these `DeliveryAttempts`.

Note that you can use [`.auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [`.auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) instead of `default` on `DateTimeField`

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    title_2 = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())

class DeliveryAttempts(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='attempts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attempted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You do not necessarily need to `annotate` your `QuerySet` you could implement a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) and count related objects which is way simpler. But, since you asked, here is one way to do it:

views.py

```
class OrderListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = (
            super().get_queryset()
            .prefetch_related('attempts')
            .annotate(attempts_count=Count('attempts'))
        )
        return qs
```

serialiers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attempts = serializers.IntegerField(source='attempts_count')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_id', 'title', 'title_2', 'updated_at', 'attempts']
```

#### Alternatively

Since you cannot change your `Model`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()

    data = []
    for obj in qs:
        order = model_to_dict(obj, exclude=['attempts'])
        order['attempts'] = qs.filter(attempts=order['id']).count()
        data.append(order)

    return data
```

You would also have to adapt your `serializer`:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attempts = serializers.IntegerField()
    driver = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_driver(self, obj):
        return Driver.objects.get(id=obj['driver']).id
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it isn't fit for me because I need data to CSV report and need annotate my QS.

Comment: The QS is annotated. You mean you cannot change your `Model`?

Comment: Yes I have something like that Order.objects.fiter(**filter_conditions).anotate(attempts_count=Count('attempts'), ...) but it always return 1

Comment: That is because you have a `FK` pointing to `one` record of `Order`. For that to work you would need a `ManyToManyField`. Since you said you cannot change your `Model` then it is a dead end. There is no way to  `annotate` with the current design, what you can do is transform data, I will append an example to my answer.

Comment: But if I modified My model to `ManyToManyField` I add many unuseless data because in table I will get reversible id's because I have `self` relationship.

Comment: Not really futile. In this way you would be able work with the framework  `relationships` and properly annotate your data, just as my first solution proposal which is more consistent relation wise (since an `attempt ` is only related to one `order`). I also tried to look into django [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) but it does not seem to offer any solution for `counting` objects.